# gdb fails when checking conditions at breakpoints

Tags: c++, c, gdb

I define a breakpoint by

```
b foo:124 if strcmp(bar::foo::getName(), "abc")==0
```

But gdb fails with the following errors

```
[Thread 0x7fffe8ef9700 (LWP 25817) exited]
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffdfc2f700 (LWP 25972)]
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
Couldn't get registers: No such process.
An error occurred while in a function called from GDB.
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(bar::foo::getName() const) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
Selected thread is running.
```

Comment: Is your program multi-threaded ? Try to change it into single-threaded, and I think it won't occur. For now I cannot explain why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `b foo:124 if strcmp(bar::foo::getName(), "abc")==0`

Such a condition is Really Bad Idea(TM) for two reasons:

1. If the application state is corrupted (even temporarily) and `getName` dereferences memory, it will likely crash, producing exactly the confusing output you've observed.
2. In order for GDB to evaluate `"abc"`, it must synthesize these bytes "inside" the program being debugged. It does this by synthesizing a call to `strdup`, and leaks the resulting memory. That can also terminate the program being debugged.

**Update:**

> I found my program generates incorrect results for the element with name "abc". There are millions of elements. So I wanted to use gdb to stop at some code when the element name is "abc".

There are few techniques you could use.

The easiest is to insert this code into your program:

```
const char *const name = getName();
if (strcmp(name, "abc") == 0) {
  if (0) printf("here\n");  // set a breakpoint here 
}
```

The advantage here is: it's much faster for the program to evaluate the condition than it is for GDB. And instead of having GDB stop on every invocation of the routine that generates results, you only stop on "interesting" invocations (also much faster).

The disadvantage is that you have to rebuild the program, and sometimes that makes the bug hide.

Another possible technique is to examine the data that `getName` returns directly (instead of calling `getName()`) -- GDB can access private data. If `getName` looks like this:

```
const char *getName() { return name_; }
```

then you can re-formulate your condition like so:

```
b foo.cc:124 if (name_[0] == 'a' && name_[1] == 'b' && name_[3] == 'c' && name_[4] == '\0')
```

This eliminates both problems with your initial approach, but is a bit verbose.

Comment: Is there any other way to debug this w/o conditional breakpoint?

Comment: @JoeC I am sure there is. You haven't explained what it is you are trying to debug though.

Comment: I found my program generates incorrect results for the element with name "abc". There are millions of elements. So I wanted to use gdb to stop at some code when the element name is "abc". Then I can debug. ideally I should simplify the test case, but I did not find a way to simply it to reproduce the issue...

Comment: You can give "abc" as input to the program you are debugging, via a file or otherwise and then start debugging

Comment: @EmployedRussian Do you know why GDB needs to leak memory after calling strcmp? I know before the code runs, gdb knows nothing how to compile the condition code, but when the code first stops, gdb should know type info of all open variables used by conditions, and it can compile the code on the fly. Why does it still need strdup?

Comment: @JoeC I believe GDB doesn't special-case `strcmp` and treats it as any other function. And GDB *cant't know* whether an arbitrary function will retain a pointer passed into it, so it can't `free` the memory without risk of introducing dangling pointer into the target program. Leaking is the lesser evil here.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Can GDB not call strdup? If so, we would not have the memory leak.

Comment: @JoeC It can't. See #2 from the initial answer: GDB must synthesize the `"abc"` in the inferior process somehow.

Comment: @EmployedRussian "abc" appears in GDB's conditional code. Does GDB synthesize it as compiling C code? In C, we treat constant strings as global data (stored in some data section?) If GDB does the same thing, it would not leak. Maybe I did not understand the difficulty that GDB has to resolve...

Comment: @JoeC "Does GDB synthesize it as compiling C code?" -- no. "constant strings as global data (stored in some data section?)" -- expression needs to be evaluated *in the context of inferior process*, and there is no usable `"abc"` inside of its data section, so GDB needs to *manufacture* one.

Comment: I found in multi-threaded programs, conditional breakpoints will be very likely to cause the above issues.

Answer (score -1):

In my case simply `continue`ing one more time ended up hitting the desired breakpoint condition.