# Conditional breakpoints on string in gdb debugger

Tags: string, find, gdb, strcmp, conditional-breakpoint

Trying to set a conditional breakpoint to stop at a specific value of a string.

Following set of commands I have tried:

**Set 1:**

```
(gdb) b file.C:97 if strcmp(pName, "abc") == 0
```

**set 2:**

```
(gdb) b file.C:97
(gdb) cond 1 !strcmp(pName, "abc")
```

**set 3:**

```
(gdb) b file.C:97
(gdb) set $str = "abc"
(gdb) cond 1 strcmp (pName, $str) == 0
```

Both of these are ending with a segmentation fault at STL of `strcmp`:

```
Continuing.
Detaching after fork from child process 12742.
Detaching after fork from child process 12818.
Detaching after fork from child process 12819.
FUSION: detected debugger running, not catching non-fusion exceptions

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse42 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp.S:260
Error in testing breakpoint condition:
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(__strcmp_sse42) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.

Breakpoint 1, __strcmp_sse42 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp.S:260
/usr/src/debug/glibc-2.12-2-gc4ccff1/sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp.S:260:7925:beg:0x32f912871a
```

Using `find()` is not ending up with segmentation fault, but the breakpoint is stopping without applying  the condition:

```
(gdb) b file.C:97
(gdb) set $str = "abc"
(gdb) cond 1 pName.find($str) == 0
```

These above commands I have tried on `GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-47.el6`

If I try `GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1.90.20180726-git`, it's ending with a new issue.

Though `pName` is defined as string,

I am getting the following after stopping debugger at breakpoint(without the condition using `strcmp()`):

```
(gdb) print pName
4: (string)pName = {static npos = <optimized out>, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x2aebca8 "xyz"}}
```

On `GDB 7.6.1-47.el6`, after applying simple breakpoint(without any condition), print pName only gives `'xyz'`.

Is it possible to do the same in `GDB 8.1.90.20180726`?

Anyway, please suggest me a way to put the condition breakpoint on string successfully!

Comment: A possibly better answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43773713/50617).

Answer (score 0):

This one has worked on `GDB 7.6.1-47.el6`!

```
(gdb) b file.C:97
(gdb) cond 1 ((int)strcmp(pName.c_str(), "abc")) == 0
```

Please let me know if anyone has a better answer!

Comment: This used to work for me too. But after updating to gcc 12 and gdb 12, I get the error `Error in testing breakpoint condition: Invalid type combination in equality test`. Somehow gdb thinks strcmp returns void... Very weird. ```(gdb) p strcmp(pName.c_str(), "abc")
$7 = void```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `.compare` method, such as

```
condition 1 pName.compare("abc") == 0
```

I succeed with GNU gdb (GDB) 14.0.50.20230225-git